# how to get an enum from another script in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

I am trying to create a win condition script pulling the status of an enum from a different script and then do stuff with it.

```
crowd.cs

public enum crowdOptions {None, TeamA, TeamB};
public crowdOptions Crowd;

Crowd = crowdOption.None;
```

I have the crowd doing a bunch of stuff, but lets say it is set to none.

```
winning.cs

if (Crowd = crowdOption.None){
     do something
} else if (Crowd = crowdOption.TeamA){
     do something
} else {
   do something
}
```

I tried a GetComponent and set the result of of Crowd to a newvariable, but I don't think I did that right

```
public CrowdSway = GameObject.Find("crowdManager").GetComponent<CrowdManager>();
```

I also tried

```
if (CrowdManager.Crowd = crowdOptions.None) {
        print("none");
    } else {
        print("hmmmmmm");
    }
```

that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access the Crowd enum variable in your crowd.cs class from another script, that script needs to have an instance of a Crowd object.  For example:

```
public class Crowd : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum crowdOptions {None, TeamA, TeamB};
    public crowdOptions crowdOpts;
}

public class Winning : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Crowd myCrowd = new Crowd();

        if(myCrowd.crowdOpts == crowdOptions.None)
        {
            //do something
        }
     }
}
```

Alternatively, you could also make your crowdOptions enum variable static.  Then you can access it from any script by name.

```
public class Crowd : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum crowdOptions {None, TeamA, TeamB};
    public static crowdOptions CrowdOptions;
}

public class Winning : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        if(CrowdOptions == Crowd.crowdOptions.None)
        {
            //do something
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  you changed "public crowdOptions Crowd;" to "public crowdOptions crowdOpts;"  So I will have to map this all out in my head again.

Comment: I get an error that says crowdOptions does not exist.  I went with the top solution. void Start () {
  CrowdManager myCrowd = new CrowdManager();

  if(myCrowd.crowdOpts == crowdOptions.None){
   print("hello");
  }
 }

Comment: I went with the second one, but I had to do if(Crowd.CrowdOptions == Crowds.crowdOptions.None)

Comment: Woops, sorry I left that out!  I have edited the answer.